# css transition on three floated elements with relative width

Tags: css, hover, transition

i have a problem with hovering three floated elements with relative width and css3 transition set.

Hovered element has 50% width, two remaining elements have 25% each, therefore all elements combined should have 100% width.

When I am hovering between two elements, everything seems fine, but when I hover over all of them, there is a moment, when elements combined do not have 100% width.

Is there a way to fix this? With diffent transtion-duration on each element or something of the sort?

Here is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tolchai/T6gPM/

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li class='row-1'></li>
    <li class='row-2'></li>
    <li class='row-3'></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul {
    background: black;
    height: 500px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

ul:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
    clear:both;  
}

ul > li {
    width: 33.33%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;   
    transition: width .5s linear;
}

ul:hover > li {
    width: 25%;
}

ul:hover > li:hover {
    width: 50%;
}

.row-1 {
    background: red;
}

.row-2 {
    background: yellow;
}

.row-3 {
    background: green;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: How do you hover over all of them at the same time? Do you have three mice / mouses?

Comment: @Paulie_D You move your cursor over all three quickly rather than slowly from one to the other.  If you time it right, the delay causes all three columns to be transitioning at the same time but not always equalling 100% width.

Comment: Sounds like a minor issue that could be solved with a background color on the container: http://jsfiddle.net/T6gPM/1/

Comment: @Paulie_D assuming the green is not just for testing purposes. Highly unlikely. :P

Comment: @paulie: unfortunately this is only a simplified fiddle, in real situation there are photos in the background, not just colors.

Comment: @MatoušBarnat Wait... what about Paulie_D's idea but removing the background to the third cell?  Would that work?

Comment: Possible solution including images: http://jsfiddle.net/T6gPM/2/

Comment: @MatoušBarnat  I know this is assuming a lot about what you're trying to do, but maybe you should think about it like this:  You have a primary image and then you have to other images that take up two-thirds of your original image space.  Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/X2fCX/

Comment: @Paulie_D exactly.  The only issue now is whether or not it is a problem that the third image is 3 times larger than the other two.

Comment: @Joseph Marikle all of my images are the same size. Until the OP adds a more specific requirement it's hard to help further. I'm just domenstrating that this is is solvable using my original solution as a basis.

Answer (score 1):

Although I considered this an unlikely edge-case / scenario (users just don't usually move their cursors around like that), just give the contianier the same bg color as the last floated `li`

[**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/T6gPM/1/)

```
ul {
    background: green; /* same as last child */
    height: 500px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: very nice workaround, I don't think we have an easy direct solution (maybe it does not even exist with pure CSS or maybe it becomes very complicated)

Comment: It's not a nice workaround.  :P The developer asking the question specifically stated there will be images in these instead of flat colors.  This does not work.

Comment: There's nothing in the OQ about images (that was an after-comment) but still, I think it could still work if one positions the images right: http://jsfiddle.net/T6gPM/2/

Comment: @Paulie_D: Thank you for the effort, I will definitely try to work with your example, thought the real situation is a bit more complex.

Comment: So is it possible that there is no pure CSS solution of this problem (keeping 100% combined width of elements) and Javascript workaround may be the only option?